# Jupyter hangs on downloading links, and can't interrupt it

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, urllib, jupyter-lab

I have a list of image links that I'm downloading, it hangs after a minute, doesn't download more links, doesn't show errors, doesn't get interrupted.

this is my code, is there something wrong with it?

```
import requests
import os
from tqdm import tqdm
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import urljoin, urlparse
from random import randint
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError

def random_with_N_digits(n):
    range_start = 10**(n-1)
    range_end = (10**n)-1
    return randint(range_start, range_end)


def download2(url, pathname):
    filename = os.path.join(pathname,str(random_with_N_digits(10))+'-'+url.split("/")[-1])
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)

done = []
failed = []

for i in urls:
    if i not in done:
        if i not in failed:
            try:
                download2(i,'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/downloaded/')
                print(i)
                done.append(i)
            except (HTTPError,URLError) as e:
                print('exception at',i)
                print(e)
                failed.append(i)
                pass
```

UPDATE:

based on the comments, printing the url before downloading it results in different urls:

first trial

```
for i in urls:
    print("for i in urls",i)
    if i not in done:
        if i not in failed:
            try:
                download2(i,'C:/Users/abdelrahman.fathy/Desktop/downloaded/')
                print(i)
                done.append(i)
            except (HTTPError,URLError,OSError) as e:
                print('exception at',i)
                print(e)
                failed.append(i)     

for i in urls http://amphenol.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/iso-9001-1.jpg
exception at http://amphenol.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/iso-9001-1.jpg
HTTP Error 410: Gone
for i in urls http://apscopower.com/about_us/iso/files/stacks-image-25baec8-606x800.png
```

second trial's outuput

```
http://image.hanrun.com/image/94db9804-fb66-41b2-a6c3-5a38c8b9eb69.jpg
for i in urls http://images02.cdn86.net/kps01/M00/2A/9C/wKiAiVRlaxrc7XGAAAFnIr8s0z4434.jpg
http://images02.cdn86.net/kps01/M00/2A/9C/wKiAiVRlaxrc7XGAAAFnIr8s0z4434.jpg
for i in urls http://images02.cdn86.net/kps01/M00/31/EB/wKiAiVR7y_CMgBErAAFz2tipXbA040.jpg
```

UPDATE 2:

```
urls = []
for i in df.imgsrc:
    if i.strip() not in urls:
        urls.append(i.strip())
len(urls)

2466
```

Comment: try proper debug method, first print all urls, then print url in for loop first line, to see which url is being worked on. this might help you to understand

Comment: @faheem I did, it's not a specific URL, each time it's a different one, and all are just normal jpg URLs

Comment: does the URL change in a loop? or does it get stuck at a single URL?

Comment: @faheem it does change

Comment: can you print url before using it in download function, that might give us clue about which url it get stuck at. right now you are printing it after download

Comment: @faheem I'm telling you I changed the code and printed `i` right after `for i in urls:` , it's a different URL each time, I'm gonna update the question for you to make sure

Comment: well there is no error in code, it is either a url which has huge file which take time to download.

Comment: maybe you are sending too many request so the server blocked your IP to stop DOS attack

Comment: @faheem they are different websites

Comment: the code and urls that you provided generate no such issue, can you tell me how many images does it download before it hangs up?

Comment: at the first trial it downloaded 7, the second it downloaded 20+

Comment: how many url are there in total? are you sure that there are more url in you list? can you print length of url before for loop

Comment: and make sure that URL are new, since you have if condition that stop old url from being used. compare urls wth previous

Comment: with each trial since i can't interrupt the kernel I just restart it so all variables are gone, `urls` is a list from a dataframe with 2466 unique urls. question updated